# Does Subversion lock paths individually? Can it be done in a grouped mode?

Tags: bash, svn

When using the [lock command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.lock.html):

```
svn lock TARGET...
```

You can specify multiple target paths to lock. When these are being locked, does Subversion repeat the process for each target? I suspect that it does, because the [pre-lock hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-lock.html) is passed 5 arguments, one of which is a (single) target path. The post-lock hook differs, passing all of the paths via stdin.

That limits what can be done with the pre-hook script; if this is the case, is there a way to access all of the target paths before the lock is processed?

For context: I'm attempting to run a command on all of the paths before the lock is given. This command will return an error that's visible to the user. When I request a lock on 2 or more paths, the error is correctly returned, but only for the first path.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-lock hook script will check all the paths that needs to be locked. The variable $PATH will have this value. In case you are trying to lock more than one file, say 3, the variable `$PATH` will go through all the three files and its value will change three times during the run time.

You can see this very clearly just by adding the below line in the pre-lock.

`echo $PATH >>/tmp/path.txt`

After locking the file, path.txt will contain all the three paths that you have locked.

However, the below command will show only one path as the variable $PATH contains only 1 value at a time.

`echo $PATH >/tmp/path.txt`

May be able to help better, if you can update with the exact requirements and the scripts that you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So does the pre-lock hook script run once for each path? Or does it run once, iterating through the paths?

The script I'm running will return the status of the locked path in the error message. Essentially, it's just running `svn stat -u` on the path whenever the lock is rejected. However, when I select multiple paths for locking, it will only display one. Could the error for the first path be stopping the script?

Comment: I suspect this is because the script exits with an error status, but only one path is available as `$PATH` at the time of the exit. Is there any way to access all paths that were locked?